# How to tune the SQL query with self join with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, self-join

I have written below query in my cursor statement to update multiple table also having insert process too through procedure as batch.

But this procedure batch taken more than 30 minutes to complete

Each time it may take to process around 400k records. Tables joined in the query have 6 million records in table called G_FOR_TB and other tables have around 1 million records. How to tune the below query?

```
SELECT rs_g_read_flg ,
  RS_SYS_ID ,
  RESP.RSH_SYS_ID ,
  INTM.ENTRY_KEY ,
  PY.POLICY_KEY ,
  CLM.CLAIM_KEY ,
  RSH_SYS_ID ,
  RSH_INTM_NO           AS INTIM_NUM ,
  RSH_POLICY_NO         AS POLICY_NUM ,
  RSH_CLAIM_NO          AS CLAIM_NUM ,
  RESP.RSH_FOR_NO       AS FOR_ID ,
  RSH_REPRESEN_CD AS REPRESEN_CDE ,
  RSH_REPRESEN_NM AS REPRESENT_NM ,
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(RSH_STS) LIKE '%No Required%' AND NVL(UPPER(RSH_GLX_STS) ,'NA')<>'BOOK LEVEL CLOSE' THEN COALESCE(RSH_FOR_NOT_REQ_REASON ,RSH_SFOREX_COMNT)
    WHEN UPPER(RSH_STS) LIKE '%No Required%' AND NVL(UPPER(RSH_GLX_STS) ,'NA')='BOOK LEVEL CLOSE' THEN RSH_SFOR_CLOSE_REMARKS
    ELSE RSH_SFOREX_COMNT
  END                AS EX_COMMENTS ,
  EMP.EMPLOYEE_KEY   AS Booked_BY ,
  EMP.EMP_FIRST_NAME AS Booked_BY_NAME ,
  RSH_Booked_DT  AS Booked_DATE ,
  NULL               AS BOOK_VISITED_DATE ,
  CASE
    WHEN RSH_DOC_REC_YN='Y' THEN 1
    WHEN RSH_DOC_REC_YN='N' THEN 0
    ELSE NULL
  END DOC_REC_FLAG ,
  RSH_DOC_REC_DT         AS REPORT_RECEIVED_DATE ,
  RSH_REBOOKED_YN        AS REBOOKED_FLAG ,
  RSH_FOR_NOT_REQ_REASON AS REASON_NOT_REQUIRED ,
  RSH_REPRESENT_MOB   AS REPRESENTATIVE_MOBILE_NO ,
  RSH_REPRESENT_TEL   AS REPRESENTATIVE_TEL_NO ,
  CASE
    WHEN RSH_STS                                  ='Booked'         THEN 51
    WHEN RSH_STS                                  ='SFOR Auto Skipped' THEN 52
    WHEN RSH_STS                                  ='DELIVERED'          THEN 5
    WHEN RSH_STS                                  = 'No Required' AND NVL(RSH_GLX_STS ,
      'No Required by Executive at ENTRY Level') =
      'No Required by Executive at ENTRY Level' THEN 217
    WHEN RSH_STS = 'No Required' AND RSH_GLX_STS =
      'BOOK LEVEL CLOSE'            THEN 218
    WHEN RSH_STS ='Rebooked' THEN 51
    ELSE NULL
  END AS STATUS_ID ,
  CASE
    WHEN RSH_STS  ='Booked'                          THEN 'ISFOR'
    WHEN SFOR.STATUS_ID = 51 AND rs_sts ='No Required' THEN 'WSFOR'
    WHEN SFOR.STATUS_ID = 49 AND rs_sts ='No Required' THEN 'ISFOR'
    WHEN RSH_STS  ='DELIVERED'                           THEN 'WSFOR'
    WHEN RSH_STS  ='Rebooked Closed'                   THEN
      'REBOOKEDCLOSEDFROMGLX'
    WHEN RSH_STS ='Rebooked' THEN 'ISFOR'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS PRESENT_LIST ,
  CASE
    WHEN RSH_STS ='Booked'        THEN 'ISFORWSFOR'
    WHEN RSH_STS ='No Required'    THEN 'ISFORSMBT'
    WHEN RSH_STS ='DELIVERED'         THEN 'ISFORWSFOR'
    WHEN RSH_STS ='Rebooked Closed' THEN 'REBOOKEDCLOSEDFROMGLX'
    WHEN RSH_STS ='Rebooked'      THEN 'ISFORWSFOR'
    ELSE NULL
  END                AS OUTCOME ,
  RSH_CALL_OPTION  AS CALL_OPTION ,
  RSH_CAL_REMARK AS CALL_REMARKS ,
  RSH_CAL_MADE    AS CALL_MADE ,
  CASE
    WHEN RSH_ID_REP='Level 1' THEN 1901
    WHEN RSH_ID_REP='Level 2' THEN 1902
    WHEN RSH_ID_REP='Level 3' THEN 1903
  END         AS ALLOTED_ID ,
  RSH_CR_DT AS CRT_DATE ,
  RSH_GLX_YN ,
  RSH_SFOR_UPDATE_YN ,
  RSH_G_UPD_YN ,
  RSH_G_UPD_DATE ,
  FOR_CNT.CNT                        AS SFOR_COUNT ,
  UPPER(RESP.RSH_CODE) AS RSH_CODE ,
  SFOR.SFOR_KEY ,
  SFOR.status_iD AS SFOR_STATUS_ID
  
FROM RESPONSE_HIST RESP
LEFT JOIN RESPONSE RES
ON RES.RS_SYS_ID = RESP.RSH_SYS_ID
LEFT JOIN POLICY_TB PY
ON PY.POLICY_NUM=RESP.RSH_POLICY_NO
LEFT JOIN INTIM_TB INTM
ON RESP.RSH_INTM_NO=INTM.INTIM_NUM
LEFT JOIN CLAIM_tb CLM
ON CLM.CLAIM_NUM=RESP.RSH_CLAIM_NO
LEFT JOIN EMPLOY_MAS EMP
ON UPPER(EMP.EMP_ID)=UPPER(RESP.RSH_CODE)
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT RS_FOR_NO ,
    COUNT(*)CNT
  FROM RESPONSE R
  WHERE (( NVL(RS_G_YN ,'N')  ='N'
  AND R.RS_FOR_NO              IS NOT NULL )
  AND ( rs_sts              IN ('Rebooked' ,'Rebooked Closed')
  OR rs_sts                 IN ('Rebooked' ,'No Required stopped')))
  OR (NVL(RS_G_YN ,'N')       ='Y'
  AND NVL(RS_FOR_UPDATE_YN ,'N')='Y'
  AND NVL(RS_G_UPD_YN ,'N')   ='N'
  AND R.RS_FOR_NO              IS NOT NULL
  AND ( rs_sts              IN ('Rebooked' ,'Rebooked Closed')
  OR rs_sts                 IN ('Rebooked' ,'No Required stopped')) )
  GROUP BY RS_FOR_NO
  ) FOR_CNT
ON RESP.RSH_FOR_NO=FOR_CNT.RS_FOR_NO
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT RS_FOR_NO ,
    COUNT(*)CNT_NR
  FROM RESPONSE R
  WHERE (R.RS_FOR_NO IS NOT NULL )
  AND ( rs_sts    IN ('No Required' ,'Rebooked Closed')
    )
  GROUP BY R.RS_FOR_NO
  ) FOR_CNT_NR
ON RESP.RSH_FOR_NO=FOR_CNT_NR.RS_FOR_NO
LEFT JOIN G_FOR_TB SFOR
ON RESP.RSH_FOR_NO=SFOR.FOR_ID
WHERE
  ( NVL(rs_g_read_flg ,'N')='N'
AND UPPER(RSH_STS)        <> 'DELIVERED'
AND (SFOR.STATUS_ID             <> 5
OR SFOR.STATUS_ID               IS NULL) )
ORDER BY RESP.RSH_SYS_ID ,
  RESP.RSH_FOR_NO ;
```

Note: I am using oracle 12c.
Index for joining columns are implemented.

Comment: Please, provide execution plan for the statement. No one can guess the reason of slow query processing. Also I may guess, that those 30+ columns are not related to poor performance, but make the code very hard to read

Comment: "this procedure batch taken more than 30 minutes to complete" - why do you think that the problem is in that query? How did you analyze it? SQL execution time/plans/statistics? PL/SQL Profiler? Traces?

Answer (score 0):

> this procedure batch taken more than 30 minutes to complete

why do you think that the problem is in that query? How did you analyze it? SQL execution time/plans/statistics? PL/SQL Profiler? Traces?

Anyway, besides this, I see a few strange things here:

1. `UPPER(EMP.EMP_ID)=UPPER(RESP.RSH_CODE)` - are they really varchar columns? If yes, why do you allow both uppercase and lowercase and don't know their letter case? Don't you use foreign keys?
2. There is no need to join aggregates by RESPONSE twice (`FOR_CNT` and `FOR_CNT_NR`). This part

```sql
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT RS_FOR_NO ,
    COUNT(*)CNT
  FROM RESPONSE R
  WHERE (( NVL(RS_G_YN ,'N')  ='N'
  AND R.RS_FOR_NO              IS NOT NULL )
  AND ( rs_sts              IN ('Rebooked' ,'Rebooked Closed')
  OR rs_sts                 IN ('Rebooked' ,'No Required stopped')))
  OR (NVL(RS_G_YN ,'N')       ='Y'
  AND NVL(RS_FOR_UPDATE_YN ,'N')='Y'
  AND NVL(RS_G_UPD_YN ,'N')   ='N'
  AND R.RS_FOR_NO              IS NOT NULL
  AND ( rs_sts              IN ('Rebooked' ,'Rebooked Closed')
  OR rs_sts                 IN ('Rebooked' ,'No Required stopped')) )
  GROUP BY RS_FOR_NO
  ) FOR_CNT
ON RESP.RSH_FOR_NO=FOR_CNT.RS_FOR_NO
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT RS_FOR_NO ,
    COUNT(*)CNT_NR
  FROM RESPONSE R
  WHERE (R.RS_FOR_NO IS NOT NULL )
  AND ( rs_sts    IN ('No Required' ,'Rebooked Closed')
    )
  GROUP BY R.RS_FOR_NO
  ) FOR_CNT_NR
```

can be rewritten to

```sql
outer apply (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(
        case when 
         rs_sts IN ('Rebooked' ,'Rebooked Closed','No Required stopped')
         and (     NVL(RS_G_YN ,'N')  ='N'
              OR (
                   NVL(RS_G_YN ,'N')        ='Y'
               AND NVL(RS_FOR_UPDATE_YN,'N')='Y'
               AND NVL(RS_G_UPD_YN ,'N')    ='N'
              )
            )
        then 1 end
    ) as CNT,
    COUNT(case when rs_sts IN ('No Required' ,'Rebooked Closed') then 1 end) as FOR_CNT_NR
  FROM RESPONSE R
  WHERE R.RS_FOR_NO = RESP.RSH_FOR_NO
) FOR_CNT
```